# Bayes Theorem Q.

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have 30% chance to have cavity gene. If I do have the   gene, there is 61% chance that I will have at least one cavity over 1 year. If I don’t have the gene, there is 29% chance that I will have at least one cavity over 1 year. Given that I have a cavity in 6 months, what’s the probability that I have at least a cavity over 1 year?

So my approach was something along the lines of:

$$P(\text{gene}|\text{cavity}) = \frac{0.30 \cdot 0.61}{0.30 \cdot 0.61 + 0.7 \cdot 0.29}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You seem to know that this has to do with Bayes' theorem. Have you tried applying it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Arthur I tried applying it but I am not getting the same answer as the book. I am only out by a little bit, but the rounding affects the answer when  calculating the revised probability.

Comment: The phrasing is slightly off...if you have a cavity in 6 months then of course you have one in a year.  I suppose they mean "what is the probability that you will have a cavity in the next year" (and that we are too assume that having cavities in consecutive time blocks are independent events).  In that case, as you seem to suggest, you need to use Bayes to re-estimate your two probabilities. You have already shown how to re-estimate the probability that you have the gene.  Now you need to re-estimate the probability that you don't (or just subtract what you computed from 1).

Comment: What is cavity gene (I read at first Calamity Jane :) ) ?

Comment: Does this sound right

P( cavity 2 | cavity 1) = 183/386 * 0.61 + 203/386 * 0.29

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on exactly this topic today. It is an introduction to Bayes Theorem it will help give you a little better understanding of what is going on here. Check it out here:  http://jeffreyfreeman.me/conditional-probabilities-and-bayes-theorem/

So what we know going in based on the world problem is the following

$$ P(gene) = \frac{3}{10} $$

$$ P(cavity|gene) = \frac{61}{100} $$

$$ P(cavity|gene^*) = \frac{29}{100} $$

What we need next in order to solve this problem is the unconditional probability on having a cavity within a year.

$$ P(cavity) $$

Luckily we have enough information to answer that. If we calculate the joint probability for cavity and gene, and add that to the join probability for cavity and the not having the gene, then we will arrive at the unconditional probability for having a cavity.

$$ P(cavity) = P(cavity, gene) + P(cavity, gene^*) $$

For that we can easily solve using our current knowns.

$$ P(cavity, gene) = P(cavity|gene) \cdot P(gene) $$

$$ P(cavity, gene^*) = P(cavity|gene^*) \cdot P(gene^*) $$

$$ P(gene^*) = 1 - P(gene) $$

Plug in known values and solve and we get a bit more information we can work with.

$$ P(cavity, gene) = \frac{61}{100} \cdot \frac{3}{10} = \frac{183}{1000} $$

$$ P(gene^*) = 1 - \frac{3}{10} = \frac{7}{10} $$

$$ P(cavity, gene^*) = \frac{29}{100} \cdot \frac{7}{10} = \frac{203}{1000} $$

Now we can solve for the probability of the cavity event as well.

$$ P(cavity) = \frac{183}{1000} + \frac{203}{1000} = \frac{193}{500} $$

At this point we can use the information we currently have and apply Bayes Theorem to figure out the chance of having the gene given that you have had a cavity recently.

$$ P(gene|cavity) = \frac{ P(cavity|gene) \cdot P(gene) }{ P(cavity) } $$

Plug in our knowns and solve.

$$ P(gene|cavity) = \frac{ \frac{61}{100} \cdot \frac{3}{10} }{ \frac{193}{500} } = \frac{193}{500} $$

So now we can finally answer the question. If you recently had a cavity what is the chance you will get another one within a year. For that lets consider the only two scenarios that can satisfy it.

In the first scenario you have the following probability: Given that I have recently had a cavity what is the probability that I have the gene and will get another cavity within a year. That question can be answered with the following statement.

$$ P(cavity|gene) \cdot P(gene|cavity) $$

The other scenario that we need to consider as an alternative way to get a cavity within a year is if you don't have the gene, but get the cavity within a year anyway. The probability for that is as follows.

$$ P(cavity|gene^*) \cdot P(gene^*|cavity) $$

These two scenarios are the only two ways you can get a cavity again in a year, either with or without the gene. Since either need to be true for the outcome to be true we can simply add the two terms to get to our final answer.

$$ P(cavity|gene) \cdot P(gene|cavity) + P(cavity|gene^*) \cdot P(gene^*|cavity) $$

$$ \frac{61}{100} \cdot \frac{193}{500} + \frac{29}{100} \cdot (1 - \frac{193}{500}) $$

$$ \frac{5169}{12500} $$

$$ 0.41352 = 41.352\% $$

So in conclusion if you have had a cavity within the last year the chance of getting a second cavity within a year of the last one would be 41.352%.